# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [48839, 7832]

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I'm a beginner in machine learning and doing my capstone project. I've built some models and I'm trying to use decision tree as the final model to predict the output from the dataset nulldata2 and store it in final_result.

But the problem is that the nulldata2 set and X_test are different sizes [48839, 7832].The nulldata2 dataset does have null data in it. I split the dataset into 2 datasets maindata from which I did the test-train-valid split and nulldata which has nullvalues and represents the original dataset.
I'm trying to check my models performance on the real dataset.

What am I doing wrong here? X_test is the trained model.

Code:

```
X_train,X_loc_test,y_train,y_loc_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.4)
#splitting into test train.
X_train.shape
(23494, 10)
X_loc_test.shape
(15664, 10)
y_train.shape
(23494, 1)
y_loc_test.shape
(15664, 1)
X_val,X_test,y_val,y_test = train_test_split(X_loc_test,y_loc_test, test_size = 0.5) #splitting into valid
X_val.shape
(7832, 10)
X_test.shape
(7832, 10)
y_val.shape
(7832, 1)
y_test.shape
(7832, 1)
nulldata.info()
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    Int64Index: 48839 entries, 0 to 49999
    Data columns (total 16 columns):
     #   Column                  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
    ---  ------                  --------------  -----  
     0   cust_number             48839 non-null  int32  
     1   buisness_year           48839 non-null  float64
     2   doc_id                  48839 non-null  float64
     3   converted_usd           48839 non-null  float64
     4   business_code_enc       48839 non-null  int64  
     5   day_of_postingdate      48839 non-null  int64  
     6   month_of_postingdate    48839 non-null  int64  
     7   year_of_postingdate     48839 non-null  int64  
     8   day_of_due              48839 non-null  int64  
     9   month_of_due            48839 non-null  int64  
     10  year_of_due             48839 non-null  int64  
     11  day_of_createdate       48839 non-null  int64  
     12  month_of_createdate     48839 non-null  int64  
     13  year_of_createdate      48839 non-null  int64  
     14  cust_payment_terms_enc  48839 non-null  int64  
     15  name_customer_enc       48839 non-null  int64  
    dtypes: float64(3), int32(1), int64(12)
    memory usage: 6.1 MB

    X_test.info()
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    Int64Index: 7832 entries, 34221 to 19423
    Data columns (total 16 columns):
     #   Column                  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
    ---  ------                  --------------  -----  
     0   cust_number             7832 non-null   int32  
     1   buisness_year           7832 non-null   float64
     2   doc_id                  7832 non-null   float64
     3   converted_usd           7832 non-null   float64
     4   business_code_enc       7832 non-null   int32  
     5   name_customer_enc       7832 non-null   int64  
     6   cust_payment_terms_enc  7832 non-null   int64  
     7   day_of_postingdate      7832 non-null   int64  
     8   month_of_postingdate    7832 non-null   int64  
     9   year_of_postingdate     7832 non-null   int64  
     10  day_of_createdate       7832 non-null   int64  
     11  month_of_createdate     7832 non-null   int64  
     12  year_of_createdate      7832 non-null   int64  
     13  day_of_due              7832 non-null   int64  
     14  month_of_due            7832 non-null   int64  
     15  year_of_due             7832 non-null   int64  
    dtypes: float64(3), int32(2), int64(11)
    memory usage: 979.0 KB

    nulldata2=nulldata[['cust_number', 'buisness_year', 'doc_id', 'converted_usd',
           'business_code_enc', 'name_customer_enc', 'cust_payment_terms_enc',
           'day_of_postingdate', 'month_of_postingdate', 'year_of_postingdate',
           'day_of_createdate', 'month_of_createdate', 'year_of_createdate',
           'day_of_due', 'month_of_due', 'year_of_due']]

    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
    regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor()
    regressor.fit(nulldata2, X_test)
    predicted = regressor.predict(nulldata2)
    
    ValueError: Number of labels=7832 does not match number of samples=48839
```

Comment: maybe post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ also for more engagement.

Comment: @kpie Thank you will do. It's in Jupyter Notebook format .ipynb

Comment: You can't really expect people to download anything.

Comment: @kpie yes another stackoverflow member pointed that out so I added the relevant code snippets. I will remove the links now. I'm sorry I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Does it work as expected? if not, then it would not be [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for Code review.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ it does not work as expected I get a Value error saying that my two DataFrames are different in length.